# What does JVM flag CMSClassUnloadingEnabled actually do?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, jvm-arguments

I cannot for the life of me find a definition of what the Java VM flag `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` actually does, other than some very fuzzy high-level definitions such as "gets rid of your PermGen problems" ([which it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333807/the-various-options-for-solving-permgen-problems/3334397#3334397), btw).

I have looked on Sun's/Oracle's site, and even [the options list](http://blogs.oracle.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html) doesn't actually say what it does.

Based upon the name of the flag, I'm guessing that the CMS Garbage Collector doesn't by default unload classes, and this flag turns it on - but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**Update** This answer is relevant for Java 5-7, Java 8 has this fixed: https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace Kudos go to [mt.uulu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076887/mt-uulu)

For Java 5-7:

The standard Oracle/Sun VM look on the world is: Classes are forever. So once loaded, they stay in memory even if no one cares anymore. This usually is no problem since you don't have that many purely "setup" classes (= used once for setup and then never again). So even if they take up 1MB, who cares.

But lately, we have languages like Groovy, that define classes at runtime. Every time you run a script, one (or more) new classes are created and they stay in PermGen forever. If you're running a server, that means you have a memory leak.

If you enable `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` the GC will sweep PermGen, too, and remove classes which are no longer used.

**[EDIT]** You will also have to enable `UseConcMarkSweepGC` (thanks to [Sam Hasler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler)). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720052/2541

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3720052/2541 for `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` to have any impact, `UseConcMarkSweepGC` must also be set

Comment: Not sure how this affects the idea of using UseConcatSweepGC, but it appears there was a bug recently fixed in CMSClassUnloadingEnabled. It is remarked as fixed here: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8000325

Comment: For languages like Groovy that dynamically define classes, is it good practice to enable this flag to periodically clean out PermGen?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, definitely. See at the bottom of http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running: "Groovy creates classes dynamically, but the default Java VM does not GC the PermGen. If you are using Java 6 or later, add `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`. `UseConcMarkSweepGC` is needed to enable `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`."

Comment: @BillR any idea how to interpret that bug report? In what version was CMSClassUnloadingEnabled set to default to true?  I couldn't work it out.

Comment: A good article about using UseConcMarkSweepGC and CMSClassUnloadingEnabled together. http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2012/06/cmsclassunloadingenabled-at-redfin.html#.VGu0efnF-So

Comment: @DavidRoussel looking at it my assumption would be that would be fixed now.

Comment: no longer valid for 1.8: https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace

Answer (score 36):

According to the blog post [The most complete list of -XX options for Java JVM](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.ch/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html), it determines if class unloading is enabled under the CMS garbage collector.  The default is `false`.  There is another option called `ClassUnloading` that is `true` by default which (presumably) affects the other garbage collectors.

The idea is that if the GC detects that a previously loaded class is no longer used anywhere in the JVM, it can reclaim the memory used to hold the classes bytecode and/or native code.

Setting CMSClassUnloadingEnabled *might* help with your permgen problem *if you are currently using the CMS collector*.  But the chances are that you are not using the CMS, or that you have a genuine classloader related memory leak.  In the latter case, your class will never appear to the GC to be unused ... and will therefore never be unloaded.

---

Aaron Digulla says "classes are for ever".  This is not strictly true, even in the purely Java world.  In fact, the lifetime of a class is tied to its classloader.  So if you can arrange that a classloader is garbage collected (and that is not always an easy thing to do) the classes that it loaded will also be garbage collected.

In fact, this is what happens when you do a hot redeploy of a webapp.  (Or at least, that's what should happen, if you can avoid the problems that lead to a permgen storage leak.)

Answer (score 23):

An example where this is useful:

Setting `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` on our Weblogic 10.3 JVM helped resolving a problem where the JAX-WS implementation created a new proxy class for every web service call, eventually leading to out of memory errors.

It wasn't trivial to trace. The following code always returned the same proxy class for `port`

```
final MyPortType port = 
Service.create(
        getClass().getResource("/path/to.wsdl"), 
        new QName("http://www.example.com", "MyService"))
    .getPort(
        new QName("http://www.example.com", "MyPortType"), 
        MyPortType.class);
```

Internally, this proxy delegated to an instance of `weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstance`, which again delegated to a new `$Proxy[nnnn]` class where `n` was incremented at every call. When adding the flags, `n` was still incremented, but at least those temporary classes were removed from memory.

On a more general note, this can be very useful when making heavy use of Java reflection and proxies through [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

Comment: +1 for sharing real experience. We also had this problem on torquebox where the server generated a huge number of classes due to JRuby compilation processes.

Comment: also note that `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` is deprecated in favor of `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

Comment: A real fix for this issue though is to create the port once and re-use it. That's how JAX-WS is supposed to be used. The port is also 100% thread safe.

Comment: @rustyx: Can you back that claim with some authoritative link? I've always been *very* wary of re-using web services proxies and stubs... E.g. see [Apache CXF disclaimers](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?). Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4385204/521799)

Comment: @Lukas Eder It's just a curious, you said: "`Weblogic` created a new proxy class for every web service call", does it mean if I make simple `get/post` request, `Weblogic` creates a new `Proxy` instance (maybe it's in the past at this moment). Does my insight correct?

Comment: @rukavitsya: As I've said in my answer. Every time I called the above logic, a new proxy was created

Comment: @Lukas Eder Does it reproduce at this time?

Comment: @rukavitsya: Hey, I'm sorry, I have no clue. That was in 2012... I work on other projects now.