# Weblogic webservice clients.(clean references)

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I created a pool of ports (webservice clients) because creating on the fly on each request the client lead to a [bottleneck](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2256583&tstart=75)

Now I noticed that the webservice clients hold references to the request and response...

Is that normal... ?

Unfortunately the payload is quite big for this websevice and like this even if not used for a while the pool holds references to some not anymore used responses...increasing heap ..

Is there a way to clean those references after receiving the response ?

Update: using Apache CXF clients i do not have this problem however pb. is still open for weblogic clients..

Comment: have you run heap-dump analysis to ensure that your assumption about held references is correct?  also, can you tell us a little more about your use-case/call pattern and how you are generating/configuring your web-service client?

Comment: Yes, i have analyzed the heap using JProfiler and that is how I discovered that.The pool is simply a LinkedList where ports are stored limited to 240.This ports are used to call a webservice.Unfortunatelly the payload is quite big and after the response arrive I would assume that should not have strong references to the response....or if there is such thing as context of the stub is never released

Answer (score 2):

@Cris: though I have not worked extensivly on weblogic web service but above issue is quite strange. You may try this:
you have pooled ports in linked list...submit invocation of a webservice call to a separate thread and once thread completes(webservice call complete), all thread local objects must be garbage collected. You need help of java profiler to find out who is holding references post webservice call..if you are using Dispatch  interface, you may print out request context and response context Map objects through BindingProvider interface to find out more..