# Is this JAX-WS client call thread safe?

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client, java-metro-framework

Since initialization of the WS client service and port takes ages I like to initialize them once at startup and reuse the same instance of the port.
Initalization would look something like this:

```
private static RequestContext requestContext = null;

static
{
    MyService service = new MyService(); 
    MyPort myPort = service.getMyServicePort(); 

    Map<String, Object> requestContextMap = ((BindingProvider) myPort).getRequestContext();
    requestContextMap = ((BindingProvider)myPort).getRequestContext(); 
    requestContextMap.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, uName); 
    requestContextMap.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pWord); 

    rc = new RequestContext();
    rc.setApplication("test");
    rc.setUserId("test");
}
```

The call somewhere in my class:

```
myPort.someFunctionCall(requestContext, "someValue");
```

My question: Will this call be thread-safe?

Comment: Has already been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385204/are-jax-ws-clients-thread-safe

Comment: Hi KHY, thanks for your quick reply. I saw this thread. My problem is, that I'm lacking of any (official) statement what is threadsafe or not (service/port/etc.). My usecase also differs from the other thread. Jonny

Comment: Here an answer I found on CXF website : https://cwiki.apache.org/CXF/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%253F

Comment: Hi KHY, this seems to answer my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. I'll just copy my previous comment as an answer then, so that this question could be closed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ%2DAreJAX%2DWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%3F):

> **Are JAX-WS client proxies thread safe?**
>
> **Official JAX-WS answer:** No.
>   According to the JAX-WS spec, the client proxies are NOT thread safe.
>   To write portable code, you should treat them as non-thread safe and
>   synchronize access or use a pool of instances or similar.
>
> **CXF answer:** CXF proxies are thread safe for MANY use cases. The
>   exceptions are:
>
> - Use of `((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext()` - per JAX-WS spec,
>     the request context is PER INSTANCE. Thus, anything set there will
>     affect requests on other threads. With CXF, you can do:
>
>   ```
>   ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context","true");
>   ```
>
>   and future calls to getRequestContext() will use a thread
>     local request context. That allows the request context to be
>     threadsafe. (Note: the response context is always thread local in CXF)
> - Settings on the conduit - if you use code or configuration to directly
>     manipulate the conduit (like to set TLS settings or similar), those
>     are not thread safe. The conduit is per-instance and thus those
>     settings would be shared. Also, if you use the FailoverFeature and
>     LoadBalanceFeatures, the conduit is replaced on the fly. Thus,
>     settings set on the conduit could get lost before being used on the
>     setting thread.
> - Session support - if you turn on sessions support (see
>     jaxws spec), the session cookie is stored in the conduit. Thus, it
>     would fall into the above rules on conduit settings and thus be shared
>     across threads.
> - WS-Security tokens - If use WS-SecureConversation or
>     WS-Trust, the retrieved token is cached in the Endpoint/Proxy to avoid
>     the extra (and expensive) calls to the STS to obtain tokens. Thus,
>     multiple threads will share the token. If each thread has different
>     security credentials or requirements, you need to use separate proxy
>     instances.
>
> For the conduit issues, you COULD install a new
>   ConduitSelector that uses a thread local or similar. That's a bit
>   complex though.
>
> For most "simple" use cases, you can use CXF proxies on multiple
>   threads. The above outlines the workarounds for the others.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.

According to the CXF FAQ http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?

> **Official JAX-WS answer:** No. According to the JAX-WS spec, the client
>   proxies are NOT thread safe. To write portable code, you should treat
>   them as non-thread safe and synchronize access or use a pool of
>   instances or similar.
>
> **CXF answer:** CXF proxies are thread safe for MANY use cases.

For a list of exceptions see the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

As you see from above answers that JAX-WS client proxies are not thread safe so I just wanted to share my implementation will others to cache the client proxies.
I actually faced the same issue and decided to create a spring bean that does the caching of the JAX-WS Client proxies. You can see more details http://programtalk.com/java/using-spring-and-scheduler-to-store/

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.BasicThreadFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * This keeps the cache of MAX_CUNCURRENT_THREADS number of
 * appConnections and tries to shares them equally amongst the threads. All the
 * connections are created right at the start and if an error occurs then the
 * cache is created again.
 *
 */
/*
 *
 * Are JAX-WS client proxies thread safe? <br/> According to the JAX-WS spec,
 * the client proxies are NOT thread safe. To write portable code, you should
 * treat them as non-thread safe and synchronize access or use a pool of
 * instances or similar.
 *
 */
@Component
public class AppConnectionCache {

 private static final Logger logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(AppConnectionCache.class);

 private final Map<Integer, MyService> connectionCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, MyService>();

 private int cachedConnectionId = 1;

 private static final int MAX_CUNCURRENT_THREADS = 20;

 private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

 private boolean forceRecaching = true; // first time cache

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  logger.info("starting appConnectionCache");
  logger.info("start caching connections"); ;;
  BasicThreadFactory factory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
    .namingPattern("appconnectioncache-scheduler-thread-%d").build();
  scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, factory);

  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    initializeCache();
   }

  }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

 }

 public void destroy() {
  scheduler.shutdownNow();
 }

 private void initializeCache() {
  if (!forceRecaching) {
   return;
  }
  try {
   loadCache();
   forceRecaching = false; // this flag is used for initializing
   logger.info("connections creation finished successfully!");
  } catch (MyAppException e) {
   logger.error("error while initializing the cache");
  }
 }

 private void loadCache() throws MyAppException {
  logger.info("create and cache appservice connections");
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CUNCURRENT_THREADS; i++) {
   tryConnect(i, true);
  }
 }

 public MyPort getMyPort() throws MyAppException {
  if (cachedConnectionId++ == MAX_CUNCURRENT_THREADS) {
   cachedConnectionId = 1;
  }
  return tryConnect(cachedConnectionId, forceRecaching);
 }

 private MyPort tryConnect(int threadNum, boolean forceConnect) throws MyAppException {
  boolean connect = true;
  int tryNum = 0;
  MyPort app = null;
  while (connect && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   try {
    app = doConnect(threadNum, forceConnect);
    connect = false;
   } catch (Exception e) {
    tryNum = tryReconnect(tryNum, e);
   }
  }
  return app;
 }

 private int tryReconnect(int tryNum, Exception e) throws MyAppException {
  logger.warn(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " appservice service not available! : " + e);
  // try 10 times, if
  if (tryNum++ < 10) {
   try {
    logger.warn(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wait 1 second");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException f) {
    // restore interrupt
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
  } else {
   logger.warn(" appservice could not connect, number of times tried: " + (tryNum - 1));
   this.forceRecaching = true;
   throw new MyAppException(e);
  }
  logger.info(" try reconnect number: " + tryNum);
  return tryNum;
 }

 private MyPort doConnect(int threadNum, boolean forceConnect) throws InterruptedException {
  MyService service = connectionCache.get(threadNum);
  if (service == null || forceConnect) {
   logger.info("app service connects : " + (threadNum + 1) );
   service = new MyService();
   connectionCache.put(threadNum, service);
   logger.info("connect done for " + (threadNum + 1));
  }
  return service.getAppPort();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for this is to use multiple client objects in a pool, then to use proxy that acts as a facade.

```
import org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObject;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultPooledObject;
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

class ServiceObjectPool<T> extends GenericObjectPool<T> {
        public ServiceObjectPool(java.util.function.Supplier<T> factory) {
            super(new BasePooledObjectFactory<T>() {
                @Override
                public T create() throws Exception {
                    return factory.get();
                }
            @Override
            public PooledObject<T> wrap(T obj) {
                return new DefaultPooledObject<>(obj);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class PooledServiceProxy<T> implements InvocationHandler {
        private ServiceObjectPool<T> pool;

        public PooledServiceProxy(ServiceObjectPool<T> pool) {
            this.pool = pool;
        }


        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            T t = null;
            try {
                t = this.pool.borrowObject();
                return method.invoke(t, args);
            } finally {
                if (t != null)
                    this.pool.returnObject(t);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getProxy(Class<? super T> interfaceType) {
        PooledServiceProxy<T> handler = new PooledServiceProxy<>(this);
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(interfaceType.getClassLoader(),
                                          new Class<?>[]{interfaceType}, handler);
    }
}
```

To use the proxy:

```
ServiceObjectPool<SomeNonThreadSafeService> servicePool = new ServiceObjectPool<>(createSomeNonThreadSafeService);
nowSafeService = servicePool .getProxy(SomeNonThreadSafeService.class);
```