# JRuby PermGen out of space even use java objects in ruby code

Tags: java, ruby, spring, jruby, applicationcontext

Description:

If we use java objects jruby get permgen too:

```
System.out.println("Initialazing..");
//Spring applicaton context
WebApplicationContext wac = (WebApplicationContext) AppContext.getApplicationContext();
// prepare path to internal ruby 
String scriptsPath = wac.getServletContext().getRealPath(RUBY_PATH);
String jrubyHome = wac.getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF" + File.separator +     "jruby");
// Initializing Scripting container
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(isShared ?     LocalContextScope.SINGLETHREAD
            : LocalContextScope.THREADSAFE, LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
// Configuring scriptingcontainer to avoid memory leaks
container.setCompileMode(RubyInstanceConfig.CompileMode.OFF);
System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.compilemode", "OFF");
System.setProperty("jruby.compile.mode", "OFF");
// Setup ruby version
container.setCompatVersion(CompatVersion.RUBY1_9);
// Set jruby home
container.getProvider().getRubyInstanceConfig().setJRubyHome(jrubyHome);
List<String> loadPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
// load path
loadPaths.add(scriptsPath);
container.getProvider().setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
// ruby dispatcher initializing and run in simple mood
String fileName = scriptsPath + File.separator + "dispatcher_fake.rb";
// run scriplet
container.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE, fileName);
// terminate container to cleanup memory without any effects
container.terminate();
container=null;
```

Scriptlet:

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('../../jruby/1.9', __FILE__)
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('../../jruby/1.9', __FILE__)
ENV['BUNDLE_BIN_PATH'] = File.expand_path('../../jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle', __FILE__)

require 'java'

ROOT_DIR = File.dirname(__FILE__)
require File.join(ROOT_DIR, "base", "xsi.rb")

# require java classes
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element


module JavaListing
  include_package "com.util.listing"
end

class A
  include JavaListing
  def run
    1000.times do |index|
      puts "iterating #{index}"
      # java class property
      prop = JavaListing::Property.new
      prop.proNo = 111
      prop.remoteID = "1111"
      prop.ownerID = "1111"
      prop.advertiserID = "1111"
      prop.title = "Atite"
      prop.summary = "Asummury"
      prop.description = "Adescription"
      # prop.images << JavaListing::Image.new("111", "Acaption")
      prop.lat = 12.23
      prop.lng = 13.21
      #prop.address = JavaListing::Address.new("Acity", "Acountry")
      prop.location = "Alocation"
      prop.policy = JavaListing::Policy.new("AcheckinAt", "AcheckoutAt")
      prop.surfaceArea = "Asurfscearea"
      # prop.notes[index] = JavaListing::Note.new("Atitle", "Atext")
      prop.order = "Aorder"
      prop.map = JavaListing::Map.new(true, 14)
      # 
      doc = Jsoup.parse("<root><elements><element>Application Error  #{index}  </element></elements></root>")
  end
end
```

As you can see we are using all java objects but Perm get aout of memory leaks still happens

If we create objects in spring application and pass Application Context to ruby for getting beans in future this didn`t ressolve this issues

> In scripting container set ApplicationContext context = Spring application context

```
container.put("$context", context);
```

> ruby code

```
bean = $context.getBean("some_name")
bean.myMethod()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use separate JVM started from current JVM:

[Start new JVM](http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/starting_a_new_jvm_in_java/)